# Eigenvalue decomposition of correlation matrix

Tags: r, eigenvalue

I have a correlation matrix:

```
cor.table <- matrix( sample( c(0.9,-0.9) , 2500 , prob = c( 0.8 , 0.2 ) , repl = TRUE ) , 50 , 50 )
diag(cor.table) <- 1
```

I try to do eigenvalue decomposition:

```
library(psych)
fit<-principal(cor.table, nfactors=50,rotate="none")
```

or

```
stopifnot( eigen( cor.table )$values > 0 )
```

In both cases I get the error:

```
Error in eigens$values < .Machine$double.eps : 
  invalid comparison with complex values
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may need a symmetric matrix - which you do not have in your example.

Comment: After making your matrix symmetric - using the same method in the answer I gave you previously (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763723/create-covariance-matrix-from-correlation-table-with-both-positively-and-negativ/18764141#18764141) - I did not get an error with `eigen(cor.table)`.

Comment: To have a valid correlation matrix, you also need to ensure that the eigenvalues are non-negative.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd how do you ensure that they are non-negative? can I still have negative correlations?

Comment: You can have both positive and negative correlations, but they must be consistent. For instance, if variables A and B have a high positive correlation (e.g., `.6`), and variables B and C have a high positive correlation (e.g, `.6`), then variables A and C cannot have a high negative correlation (e.g, `-.6`) -- but they could have a small negative correlation (e.g., `-.1`).

Comment: can you guide me in how to specify such a consistent matrix? should I post a separate question?

Comment: There are many ways of "fixing" an inconsistent variance matrix, e.g., with the `nearPD` function in the `Matrix` package (since you want a correlation matrix, you will need to call `cov2cor` afterwards), but they will not be as uniformly distributed as you may want.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem you for which you asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18763723/1623354) previously. You need a symmetric matrix.

```
set.seed(1)
cor.table <- matrix(sample(c(0.9,-0.9),2500,prob=c(0.8,0.2),repl=TRUE),50,50)
ind <- lower.tri(cor.table)
cor.table[ind] <- t(cor.table)[ind]
diag(cor.table) <- 1
```

Now when you try using `eigen` you do not get an error.

```
your.eigen <- eigen(cor.table)
> summary(your.eigen)
Length Class  Mode   
values    50   -none- numeric
vectors 2500   -none- numeric
```

Comment: Yes this produces a the symmetric matrix but principal(cor.table, nfactors=50,rotate="none") still gives an error because some of the eigenvalues are non-negative. is there a way to fix this?